# SASS: attach class to amperand operator

Tags: css, sass

My current SASS looks like this:

```
   .container {
      width: 200px;

      .element {
        color: red;
      }
   }
```

I want to achieve that ONLY containers that have the class .small have elements with color:blue. I have tried the following, but this does not work:

```
.container {
          width: 200px;

          .element {
            color: red;

            .small& {
              color: blue
            }
          }
       }
```

My desired compilation is: `.small.container .element { color: blue }`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Look at the [@at-root](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/774#issue-14854057).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider rearranging your scss like this:

```
.container {
  width: 200px;

  .element
  {
    color: red;
  }

  &.small .element
  {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

This will output follwing css:

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
}
.container .element {
  color: red;
}
.container.small .element {
  color: blue;
}
```

[Read here about the parent referencing selector of sass](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector)

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood correctly....This Sass:

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
  .element {
      color: blue;
  }
  &.small .element{
    color: red;
  }
}
```

compiles to:

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
}
.container .element {
  color: blue;
}
.container.small .element {
  color: red;
}
```

Hopes this helps